# jquery and Jplist jquery plugin table data with many pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( '#list' ).on( "click", ".list-item", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( "toto" + $(this).text());
    var $this = this;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
$('.list-item').not($this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Hello, I have a problem with the line `$('.list-item').not($this).removeClass('selected');` which doesn't work for div present in another pages when navigated. thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by anothers pages? please be clear.

Comment: hello, i have a data table with index page and each page contains 10 div of image,  i use a jquery plufin wich sort by page

Comment: jplist is the name of the plugin

Comment: Can you please add more information like the HTML of the index page and what you are attempting to do in the event?

Answer (score 0):

In the `JPList` plugin, when you `navigate` only the content of the div elements are replaced and not the complete div. So, you'll have to `reset` the selected class upon navigation or any such event.

While initializing the plugin with default options use `'redrawCallback'`

i.e.,

```
redrawCallback: function() {
  $('.list .selected').removeClass('.selected');
}
```

The above code will reset the selected class upon the div.

and also update your code to be

```
$( '#list' ).on( "click", ".list-item", function( event ) {
    $('.list .selected').removeClass('selected');
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( "toto" + $(this).text());
    var $this = this;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Try this approach, as this would first remove the existing `selected` class from the elements and add `selected` class to clicked element

Comment: thank but it does'nt work. the selected div in the first page keep selected and the other div in another page too...

Comment: Div in another page is selected because the div remains same and only the content is replaced. So while you intialise the jplist plugin with default options add `redrawCallback: function() {$('.list .selected').removeClass('.selected'); }`  This will help you!

Comment: i 'm going to find a solution with redrawcallback  yes! i understand now but i need to keep div selected while i didn't select div in another page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that particular plugin, but I looked into it and it seems it caches the 'other' pages somewhere while they are not displayed. At the moment your script is executed the elements are not existing in the DOM.

You will have to run a code similar to yours everytime the plugin loads a page:

```
// event "loadNewPage" is not an actual event; you will have to figure out which callbacks/hooks/events your plugin offers
$( '#list' ).on( "loadNewPage", function( event ) {
    $('.list-item').removeClass('selected');
});
```

This only works if your changes are cached as well, otherwise you will have to save the selected element in your javascript and reselect it everytime the plugin displays a page.

Comment: thanks but i don't understand very much the solution...i 'm going to search in the doc plugin wich event  offer.